# convert minutes to date and time c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this **minutes** number **2400**.
I need convert 2400 minutes to exact date

Like this **2400** minutes equal ==> 2012-12-17 04:00:00

Comment: do you mean starting from current Date?

Comment: Why equal? I don't see a logic.

Comment: where 0 mins is what starting date?  what have you tried already? more information is required!

Comment: What is you start time?  You have 2400 min, but from when?

Comment: Based on what, you must have some kind of a formula in mind for the conversion ?

Comment: @jclozano Yes, starting from current date

Comment: 2400 minutes are 40 hours. What logic are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you look for this:

```
        int minutes = 2400;
        var dt = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMinutes(minutes);
```

Comment: Ever heard of DateTime.Today?

Comment: @John - Well, sure.  This maximizes the odds that the OP will find the correct code if he's not talking about the current date.  Which is quite unclear in the question.

Comment: @JohnGietzen: No need to be snarky. You can just point out that DateTime.Today is equivelent to DateTime.Now.Date

Answer (score 1):

A number of *minutes* is a **time interval**, not an absolute *date*. You need to know what does the number of minutes represent, i.e. the number of minutes since what event, in order to get an absolute date.

Assuming it's the number of minutes since the beginning of, say, a specific year, you can do it like this:

```
var start = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 2400, 0);
var date = start + interval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AddMinutes function of the DateTime class:

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
    MessageBox.Show(dt.AddMinutes(2400).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1); // the start date, example 2010 jan 1

DateTime newDate =  date.AddMinutes(2400);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write,

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(2400);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Output:

```
11/30/2016 4:00:00 PM
```

But if the current time is `11/30/2016 7:00:00 AM` and if you wrilte,

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2400);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Then output will be:

```
11/30/2016 11:00:00 PM
```